# drools 6.0.0.Beta3 NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, drools

I am working with drools expert 6.0.0.Beta3 (latest available on the downloads page) and I am  trying to update a rule existing in the working memory. Basically, I am calling add() of kBuilder again, like so:

```
kBuilder.add(org.drools.io.ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(drl.getBytes()),
            org.drools.builder.ResourceType.DRL);
```

When I first add the rule, it gets added, and is even triggered when conditions meet. However, when calling add() again, as above, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.validateUniqueRuleNames(PackageBuilder.java:1314)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.initPackageRegistry(PackageBuilder.java:916)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackage(PackageBuilder.java:869)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDrl(PackageBuilder.java:474)
    at org.drools.compiler.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:670)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:51)
    at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:40)
    at org.drools.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:34)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something wrong since trying to add the same DRL twice to the KnowledgeBuilder will end up in having the same rule twice in the KnowledgeBase. Honestly I'd be curious to know why you're trying this.

Anyway you should have a compilation issue reporting the duplicated rule name and not a NPE. This is definitively a bug that I reported [here](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-180) and already fixed on the master.

Thanks for having found this.

Comment: Like I said, I am trying to update the rule. The drl for my rule is based on user input - which can change - and I want to update the drl as per the new input. Is there another way, without adding the rule again, to reflect the changes in the drl?

The stack trace does match to what you have in the bug description.